# Creating a table with partition projection results in an empty one

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm creating a table in Athena based on a list of CSV files in an S3 bucket. The files in the buckets are placed in folders like this:

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name/ --recursive
2023-01-23 16:05:01      25601 logs2023/01/23/23/analytics_Log-1-2023-01-23-23-59-59-6dc5bd4c-f00f-4f34-9292-7bfa9ec33c55
2023-01-23 16:10:03      18182 logs2023/01/24/00/analytics_Log-1-2023-01-24-00-05-01-aa2cb565-05c8-43e2-a203-96324f66a5a7
2023-01-23 16:15:05      20350 logs2023/01/24/00/analytics_Log-1-2023-01-24-00-10-03-87b03989-c059-4fca-8e8b-909e787db889
2023-01-23 16:20:09      25187 logs2023/01/24/00/analytics_Log-1-2023-01-24-00-15-06-6d9b39fb-c05f-4416-9b17-415f48e63591
2023-01-23 16:25:18      20590 logs2023/01/24/00/analytics_Log-1-2023-01-24-00-20-16-3939a0fe-8cfb-4168-bc8e-e71d2122add5
```

This is the format for the folder structure:

```
logs{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}/<filename>
```

I would like to use Athena's partition projection and this is how I'm creating my table:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE analytics.logs (
  id string, 
  ...
  type tinyint)
PARTITIONED BY (
    year bigint COMMENT '',
    month string COMMENT '',
    day string COMMENT '')
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket-name/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='csv', 
  'partition.day.values'='01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31', 
  'partition.day.type'='enum', 
  'partition.enable'='true', 
  'partition.month.values'='01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12', 
  'partition.month.type'='enum', 
  'partition.year.range'='2022,2100', 
  'partition.year.type'='integer', 
  'storage.location.template'='s3://bucket-name/logs${year}/${month}/${day}/')
```

As you can see, I'm trying to partition the data using `year`, `month`, and `day`. Even though there's also an hour folder, I'm not interested in that. This command executes just fine and it creates the table too. But when I query the table:

```sql
SELECT * FROM analytics.logs LIMIT 10;
```

It returns empty. But if I create the same table without the `PARTITIONED` part, I can see the records. Can someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

**[UPDATE]**

I simplified the folder structure to see if it works. It does not.

```
$ aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name/test --recursive
2023-01-24 07:03:30          0 test/
2023-01-24 07:03:59          0 test/2022/
2023-01-24 07:11:06      13889 test/2022/Log-1-2022-12-01-00-00-11-255f8d74-5417-42a0-8c09-97282a626903
2023-01-24 07:11:05       8208 test/2022/Log-1-2022-12-01-00-05-15-c34eda24-36d8-484c-b7b6-4861c297d857
```

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `log_2`(
  `id` string, 
  ...
  `type` tinyint)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` bigint COMMENT '')
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket-name/test'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='csv', 
  'partition.enable'='true', 
  'partition.year.range'='2021,2023', 
  'partition.year.type'='integer', 
  'storage.location.template'='s3://bucket-name/test/${year}/')
```

And still the following query returns nothing:

```sql
SELECT * FROM "analytics"."log_2" where year = 2022 limit 10;
```

Comment: Did you try running [MSCK REPAIR TABLE - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html) to recognise the existing partitions?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but when using partition projection, Athena does not need to read/reload the partitions. I mean that's the whole selling point of partition projection.

Comment: Ah. Okay, I haven't tried using partitions that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who might make my mistake, the problem is that I was (incorrectly) using `partition` in the `TBLPROPERTIES` section. While it should have been `projection`.

To provide you with a working example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `log_2`(
  id string, 
  ...
  type tinyint)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` bigint COMMENT '')
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket-name/test'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='csv', 
  'projection.enable'='true', 
  'projection.year.range'='2021,2023', 
  'projection.year.type'='integer', 
  'storage.location.template'='s3://bucket-name/test/${year}/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mismatch in data types. Partition by year is bigint and partition projection is integer. Make both integers.

```
"projection.enabled" = "true",
"projection.datehour.type" = "date",
"projection.datehour.format" = "yyyy/MM/dd/HH",
"projection.datehour.range" = "2021/01/01/00,NOW",
"projection.datehour.interval" = "1",
"projection.datehour.interval.unit" = "HOURS",
```

Change the partition word to projection.

Comment: Hi Simon and thanks for pointing out that issue. While you are right and that needs to be corrected but it didn't help. Thank you though.

Comment: Here is an sample from our tables  'projection.dt.format'='yyyy-MM-dd', 
  'projection.dt.interval'='1', 
  'projection.dt.interval.unit'='DAYS', 
  'projection.dt.range'='2022-10-02,NOW', 
  'projection.dt.type'='date', 
  'projection.enabled'='true',

Comment: change the partition to projection